# Enable shortcodes on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, filters, shortcode

I have written a plugin that uses shortcodes and I have enabled the shortcodes to be used within widgets but I also want them to be enabled within my custom post types pages.

As I understand I probably will need to add a filter for that but I can't find how to do it.

```
    //Handling the shortcodes

    function my_shortcode_init()    {

        function my_shortcode_func($atts)   {          

           //do something          

        }
        //Register the shortcode function   
        add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'my_shortcode_func');
    }
    add_action('init', 'my_shortcode_init');


    /*
    Make shortcode work within widget
    */
    add_filter( 'widget_text', 'shortcode_unautop' );
    add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Have you tested it? I believe they should just work.

Comment: There is no such restriction to use functions...

Comment: if your custom post type post uses `the_content()` to output the content, there should be no problem using the shortcodes.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to change anything to get them to work.  In your php you can just echo the shortcode:

```
// Use shortcode in a PHP file (outside the post editor).
echo do_shortcode( '' );

// In case there is opening and closing shortcode.
echo do_shortcode( '[iscorrect]' . $text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode . '[/iscorrect]' );

// Enable the use of shortcodes in text widgets.
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );

// Use shortcodes in form like Landing Page Template.
echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="91" title="quote"]' );

// Store the short code in a variable.
$var = do_shortcode( '' );
echo $var;
```